# Does inductive back-EMF create significant radiated emissions on long load wires?

Tags: emc, inductive, back-emf

So, lets say you have a mechanical switch connecting an AC (mains) source to a small inductive load (say, a single speed ceiling fan) via a long wire (1000' of NM).  When the switch is turned off, how much of the energy from the motor's back-EMF gets radiated, and what would a spectrum analyzer plot of this radiation look like were you to do this in an EMC test site?

Comment: It will depend a lot on the components I think. When the switch turns off you will have a LRC circuit, L from the fan and wire inductance), R from the wire and C from the switch parasitic capacitance. This RLC circuit will have a frequency of resonance, whose value depends on the L and C values, the higher this frequency more radiated energy you will have. Lower frequencies will turn into heat on the R portion of the circuit.

Comment: What is driving the fan: AC or DC? Is the switch a mechanical switch or a SCR or a TRIAC? Do you just want an EMI equation and this is all just theory, or do you just want to snubb it and be done with it?

Comment: @Dave -- I'm asking because I'm trying to determine *where* the snubber should go (i.e. at the contacts vs. at the load)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, then why isn't that your question? (btw, answer is load.)

Comment: @Dave -- my suspicion was load as well, but I wanted to drill down into the radiated emissions part because I didn't have good data about that specifically.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer this here, even though I've got you covered in the comments. The snubbing circuit should go at the load.

A great way of thinking about **WHY**, is that the source of the back EMF is the inductor on the fan. The farther away the snubber is from the source, the more wire there is to act like an antenna to radiate the back EMF as EMI.

Comment: That's my logic as well -- I'm just trying to find if anyone's *measured* it :)

Comment: LR circuit would produce an exponentially decaying pulse with direction negative to the current flow. Plug that into a simulator and then do an FFT on the result. That would give you the frequency signature that a broad band RF sniffer would likely see. Also the signature would change based on how far from 0V you were when you opened the mechanical relay. If you were at the peak (negative or positive) of the wave, you'd get the most emi emitted than if you were at 0V where you'd get nothing at all.